# I am facing an error "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I am new in kotlin and retrofit, when I run this app it shows nothing in my device. But I check the logcat and found this error`No adapter attached; skipping layout`.Sometimes ago I post this question, some people answer this but this answer not correct

CountryActivity.kt

```
var recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.countryRecyclerView)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

var apiInterface: CountryDataInterface = 
CountryApiClient.getApiClient()!!.create(CountryDataInterface::class.java)
apiInterface.getCountryData().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Country>> {
override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Country>>, t: Throwable) {}

override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Country>>, response: Response<List<Country>>) {
val countryData = response.body()!!
recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)
```

CountryDataAdapter.kt

```
class CountryDataAdapter(var countryDataList: List<Country>?):
RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryDataAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {
class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
var countryName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryName)
var casesTotal: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.casesTotal)
var casesToday: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.casesToday)
var deathTotal: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deathTotal)
var deathToday: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deathToday)
var recoveredAll: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recoveredAll)
var activeAll: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.activeAll)
var criticalAll: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.criticalAll)

fun bindData(countryDataList: List<Country>?, position: Int){
    countryName.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).countryName.toString()
    casesTotal.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).cases.toString()
    casesToday.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).todayCases.toString()
    deathTotal.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).deathTotal.toString()
    deathToday.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).deathToday.toString()
    recoveredAll.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).recovered.toString()
    activeAll.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).activePatient.toString()
    criticalAll.text = countryDataList!!.get(position).critical.toString()
  }
 }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
var view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.country_row,parent,false)
return RecyclerViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
return countryDataList!!.size
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
holder.bindData(countryDataList,position)
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No adapter attached , skipping layout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539865/no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-error)

Comment: no, this is not the answer. I follow but it's don't work

Comment: I think this message mislead you.  Be sure nothing is wrong with your layout. Can you share your xml?

Comment: Ofcourse @aiqency, here is my xml code https://gist.github.com/diptoroy/87338b135b0fbc826a8a8c61b2b0b27c, https://gist.github.com/diptoroy/e356e3a317a564e614c1e259030b59d1

Comment: I guess it is a typo in your post vs your layout ```R.id.countryRecyclerView``` ```android:id="@+id/cRecyclerView"```. I run your code and it is working.

Comment: no, i am changing the id name.now post vs layout are same cRecyclerView.but still now it's not working

Comment: Are you sure that ```onResponse``` is called

Comment: i am not sure,can you explain

Comment: i am not sure,can you explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is because you're calling `recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)` in your Async function.

From what your post shows

```kotlin
override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Country>>, response: Response<List<Country>>) {
val countryData = response.body()!!
recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)
```

`recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)` is in `onResponse` which is async, when your activity lunch, your adapter isn't set as it waits the result from the network to set it.

It would be better to set it to:

1. At the beginning of your activity add `var countryData: List<Country> = ArrayList()`

EDIT after checking Repo:

You get nothing because your call is getting into `onFailure`. You should add log to see this kind of things.

**CountryActivity:**

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_country)

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cRecyclerView)
        var countryData: List<Country> = ArrayList()
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)
       // recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))

        val apiInterface: CountryDataInterface = CountryApiClient.getApiClient()!!.create(CountryDataInterface::class.java)
        apiInterface.getCountryData().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Country>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Country>>, t: Throwable) {

                val data = Country(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
                countryData = listOf(data)
                recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)

                Log.d("onFailure", "ERROR")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Country>>, response: Response<List<Country>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    countryData = response.body()!!
                    recyclerView.adapter = CountryDataAdapter(countryData)
                }
            }

        })

    }
```

**Adapter:**

```kotlin
class CountryDataAdapter(private var countryDataList: List<Country>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryDataAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>() {
    class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val countryName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryName)
        val casesTotal: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.casesTotal)
        val casesToday: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.casesToday)
        val deathTotal: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deathTotal)
        val deathToday: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deathToday)
        val recoveredAll: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recoveredAll)
        val activeAll: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.activeAll)
        val criticalAll: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.criticalAll)

        fun bindData(countryDataList: List<Country>, position: Int){
            val item = countryDataList[position]
            countryName.text = item.countryName.toString()
            casesTotal.text = item.cases.toString()
            casesToday.text = item.todayCases.toString()
            deathTotal.text = item.deathTotal.toString()
            deathToday.text = item.deathToday.toString()
            recoveredAll.text = item.recovered.toString()
            activeAll.text = item.activePatient.toString()
            criticalAll.text = item.critical.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.country_row,parent,false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countryDataList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindData(countryDataList,position)
    }
}
```

Comment: I follow your suggestion but it's show new error the error is  kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.atc.awarenessforthecorona.adapter.CountryDataAdapter.getItemCount(CountryDataAdapter.kt:41)

Comment: Yeah that's because you used `!!` everywhere you should use `?` instead, you don't need it at all for in your Adapter. When you use `!!` if the var you call is null it'll cause a crash of your app

Comment: Any crash ? or logcat? or github repo that I can check ?

Comment: same error No adapter attached; skipping layout and the repo link https://github.com/diptoroy/AwarenessForTheCoronaV1.0

Comment: My post is updated. You should fix your call and it'll work ;)

Comment: Can you check this please,again i am facing this error,but this one i am working with java and volley.hope you will check this,thank u @Biscuit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957032/i-am-facing-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-error